# setNeedsDisplay breaks UIView's Auto Layout animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, drawrect

I have a UIViewController that contains two views (from two child view controllers): A top content view, and a bottom menu popup. The constraints are set up so that as the bottom menu expands, the top content view is squashed:

[image]

All the constraints are set up correctly so the subviews all layout correctly when the menu is expanded and collapsed. It even works correctly with a UIView `animateWithDuration:` block (I am calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` to update the layout of the subviews during animation).

However, one of the views within the Content View area is a custom view containing a `drawRect:` method. Every time this view updates, I am calling `setNeedsDisplay`. As soon as `setNeedsDisplay` is called for the first time, the animations for this view break and will not update its frame until `setNeedsDisplay` is called again. I cannot get it to animate with all the other views! Comment out the `drawRect:` method, or comment out the `[self setNeedsDisplay]`, and the view animates with the parent views again perfectly.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: without seing any code, I would bet that your drawings inside drawRect conflict with the constraints. Can you add some code here?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to be careful adding code here because it is strict NDA stuff, however there is little point of posting the `drawRect:` code, since merely the act of including the method with nothing in it causes the constraints to break.

Comment: if there is nothing inside, the whole method should be commented out. Try that to see what happens. I was wondering if you where using self.frame at any point. Inside drawRect it's a better practice to use self.bounds

Comment: No sorry... What I mean is, if the whole method is commented out, it works fine. If I just add a `drawRect:`, even if there is nothing in it, then the animations break. Interesting you say about `self.bounds` instead of `self.frame` - is there any reason behind that? I used `self.frame` in three places in the `drawRect:` so I have changed them to `self.bounds` now. Unfortunately it didn't make any difference though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just should let the iOS do the work for you.
If your view needs to be redrawn often, set the view's contentMode:

```
yourView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

And it should redraw when needed.